# Asp.net increase response time and sql connection time

Tags: sql, asp.net, httpresponse

I have an application in asp.net 2.0, it is using SQLHelper, I want to upgrade response time ,query execution time and sql connection time in this application. currently I have set httpHandler to following: 
    
but its only working for 15 mins, my page is loading a huge amount of data, I need to know the ways by which I can increase its performance. Currently data grid has no pagination, I set     Connect Timeout=60000; in connection string in web.config, I want to ask If there's any thing else that can be done? plus is there any thing that will avoid time consumption of 15 mins?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not able to increase command time as it is using SQLHelper

Comment: That's no excuse, you can simply edit SQLHelper to take an additional timeout parameter or you can set a static property to set the timeout. But 15 mins! I won't accept a response time past 3 seconds in my apps, and we load millions of rows in some processes. Can you describe the schema for the query that is taking so long, or simply post the query itself, I'd like to work through this with you rather than just "give you the answer" :)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I can not post query, its creating 2 view tables and in third select statement its joining those two tables, data records are in million and asp.net version is 2.0, I set maxRequestLength="2097151", I just implemented pagination it is getting data in 15 sec for a million record

Comment: I am getting timeout expired error, I have set Connect TimeOut in connection string to 60000.

Comment: Connect timeout won't help you, instead you'll need to set the execution timeout on the query itself, which will involve making changes to SQLHelper if you're set on used it. I'll post a code example when I get in front of a laptop

Comment: ok thank you Chris